# How to speed up the Aarch64 Android Emulator on X86 ubuntu 18.04

Tags: android, x86, emulation, ubuntu-18.04, arm64

I am trying to implement my tools on an APK, which can be only installed on arm-v8a or armeabi devices, so when I download the Android-23 image with arm-v8a on my ubuntu and run it, it acts really slow with the warning "Running on x86 based Android Virtual Device (AVD) is 10x faster. We strongly recommend creating a new AVD", and the speed of emulator is really slow, takes 20 mins to start the emulator and 10 - 30s delay when actions send to the device.
So is there any solution to speed up the ARM architecture emulator on x86 devices?
Or is there any way to modify the apk to be able to run on x86 emulator? Since the apk implemented with only arn64-v8a and armeabi libraries, so I don't think this could be a possible solution. However, please let me know if this solution works and how to do it.

Comment: Try asking at [https://android.stackexchange.com/](https://android.stackexchange.com/). The Android emulator is already very slow with x86 virtualized images, let alone with QEMU-ed ARM images. While it's possible I'm not sure there are tools to statically convert from ARM to x86. Eventually, try lifting the ARM binary to LLVM IR and then converting back to x86. But the easier solution would be to try a different emulator (like bluestacks) or simply buy a cheap Android phone.

Comment: Give a look to KVM. I succeed to make the emulator much faster once with that (though I do not remember the details). Note that it was *experimental* and a pain to make this work but the result was significantly faster on my machine (several times faster). Still I remember it wasn't very stable. It was something like 8-years ago so I guess it might be simpler/better now.